# Tracking Changes on insert or update or delete on a table for PostgreSQL using trigger

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am creating a table to track changes however it is returning the following error:

> "(psycopg2.InternalError) control reached end of trigger procedure
>   without RETURN CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function change_trigger()"

Whenever I perform any of the following actions : `insert`, `change` or `update`

Please see below table and trigger function

*Create table for logging changes*

```
Create schema logging;
Create table logging.history(
            id serial,
            tstamp timestamp default now (),
            schemaname text,
            tabname text, 
            operation text, 
            who text default current_user,
            new_val json,
            old_val json);
```

*Create function*

```
CREATE function
change_trigger()
RETURNS trigger as $$
BEGIN
        IF TG_OP = 'Insert'
        THEN
            Insert into logging.history (tabname, schemaname, operation, new_val)
            Values (TG_TABLE_NAME,TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_OP, row_to_json(NEW));
            RETURN NEW;
        ELSIF TG_OP = 'Update'
        THEN
            Insert into logging.history (tabname, schemaname, operation, new_val, old_val)
            Values (TG_TABLE_NAME,TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_OP, row_to_json(NEW), row_to_json(OLD));
            RETURN NEW; 
        ELSIF TG_OP = 'Delete'
        THEN
            Insert into logging.history (tabname, schemaname, operation, old_val)
            Values (TG_TABLE_NAME,TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_OP, row_to_json(OLD));
            RETURN OLD;
    END IF;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

*Link Trigger function to table:*

```
CREATE TRIGGER t AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON mytemp

   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE change_trigger();
```

For example, when I perform the following:

```
INSERT into mytemp(column1)
    VALUES ('id2323900')
```

the error returns as:

> control reached end of trigger procedure without RETURN CONTEXT: 
>   PL/pgSQL function change_trigger()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Names of tg_op are (`'INSERT', 'UPDATE', 'DELETE'`) not (`'Insert', 'Update', 'Delete'`) - case sensitive, OR change `TG_OP = 'Insert'` to `TG_OP ilike('insert')`. And I would add 'else' statement at the end with notice:

```
ELSE 
    NOTICE RAISE 'Unknown tg_op';
    RETURN OLD;
END IF;
```

Comment: That's definitely the correct answer, except you swapped `RAISE` and `NOTICE`. Actually, you should make that `RAISE EXCEPTION`.